# How to get email from twitter social API user using OAuthTokens all step for whitelisted app I have done?

Tags: twitter, integration

I have send mail to twitter team they have whitelisted my app means I got check box for getting mail id but when I am doing this hitting this url

Request url: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true`

I am getting:

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
getting mail null
```

Comment: My twitter app whitelisted but still I am getting mail Id  null

Comment: I think you need more context, i.e. are you correctly including the include_email param in the Oauth signature?

Comment: could you tell me procedure to add  including the include_email param in the Oauth signature.

Comment: It depends on your library

e.g. with joauth

https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/services/twitter/TwitterAuthInterceptor.java#L103

Comment: these all things already I have done but problem is user information I am getting but email id I am not getting, I have taken permission from twitter means my application is whitelisted still mail id is null.

Comment: Test if it works for a made up param, '/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?foo=bar'  If it gives you a authentication failure then its probably a bug in your oauth signature code.

Comment: its giving same : {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

Comment: I don't think it's a whitelisting problem for you. Just General oauth signing problem. I suggest you start there. Find examples for you chosen framework and did into why this fails.